# Do I need building control approval to install an external security camera powered by power over ethernet?

Tags: electrical, building-regulations, uk, ethernet

In the UK, I understand that to wire in a new external plug socket or light using mains voltage, I either need to get a qualified electrician to do it or have the work inspected by building control.

If I install an external security camera powered by power over ethernet, do the same regulations apply? There would be no mains voltage involved and no modifications to any circuits. Simply an ethernet cable going through the wall and wired to the camera on the outside and plugged into a router and POE injector on the inside.

Comment: Contact 'building control' and ask them.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need "Building Control" (in the UK, called planning permission) approval for this.

The requirement in UK building regulations only extends to mains voltage.  A PoE injector is typically 48 volts or lower - not something that is covered by current regulations.

Just remember to take all the usual precautions (outdoor grade cabling, secure fixings etc) and you're perfectly ok to do this.

If you still have any doubts, contact your local council planning office - it's free to make general enquiries like these as you are not trying to get concent for building works.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just to be clear though, I _am_ talking about "building control" and not planning permission, which is a different thing. For example, I probably wouldn't need planning permission to remove a load bearing internal wall, but I would certainly need to notify building control. It may be a regional thing, but at least where I live the relevant department is called "building control" - see [link](https://www.scambs.gov.uk/services/building-control)